# Pause/resume setInterval when document.hidden

Tags: javascript

I need to display an alert every 30 seconds. If user temporary switches to the other tab, the timer must freeze.

My code is following:

```
var alertIntervalId = null
var quotes = ['quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3']
var NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL = 5
var TIMEOUT_IN_SECS = 5

var alertInterval = setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
        alert(quotes[randomIdx])
    }, NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL * 1000)
}, TIMEOUT_IN_SECS * 1000)

function handleVisibilityChange(){
    if (document.hidden) {
        clearInterval(alertIntervalId)
        alertIntervalId = null
    } else {
      alertIntervalId = alertIntervalId || alertInterval()
    }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
handleVisibilityChange()
```

But the code does not working (the freezing does not occur), and I can't figure out why.

P.S. I've just started to learn JavaScript, so please consider not throwing  rotten tomatoes.

**Edit**:

After slight refactoring, the code looks like

```
var alertIntervalId = null
var quotes = ['quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3']
var NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL = 5
var TIMEOUT_IN_SECS = 5

var alertInterval = function() {
  return setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
      alert(quotes[randomIdx])
    }, NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL * 1000)
  }, TIMEOUT_IN_SECS * 1000)
}

function handleVisibilityChange(){
    if (document.hidden) {
        clearInterval(alertIntervalId)
        alertIntervalId = null
    } else {
      alertIntervalId = alertIntervalId || alertInterval()
    }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
handleVisibilityChange()
```

but alerts are still not get frozen after switching to other tab  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange to detect when the user clicks on a different tab and freeze the interval if the doc became hidden or activate it again if it became visible.

As written, you'll never know when the doc becomes hidden, since it only checks the hidden property when you run the handleVisibilityChange() function.

So I would prefer using the event listener and a single setInterval.

**Edit:**

The problem is that you have an error in your code. Open the console to see that `alertInterval` is not a function. Since you use `var alertInterval = setInterval(function() {}`, `alertInterval` will actually be the id of the interval instead of a function that returns the interval. SO change it into:

```
var alertInterval = function() {
  return setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
        alert(quotes[randomIdx])
    }, NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL * 1000)
  }, TIMEOUT_IN_SECS * 1000);
};
```

so that it stays a function that will return a new interval id.

I still haven't figured out why you use both a setInterval() and a setTimeout(), but that's probably outside of the question.

**EDIT 2:**

I've been testing this code and it works for me in IE11 and in this snippet in chrome.

So have a look at your random quotes and such.

```js
var alertIntervalId = null;
var quotes = ['quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3'];
var NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL = 5;
var TIMEOUT_IN_SECS = 5;

var alertInterval = function() {
  return setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
      console.log(quotes[randomIdx]);
    }, NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL * 1000);
  }, TIMEOUT_IN_SECS * 1000);
};

function handleVisibilityChange(){
  if (document.hidden) {
    console.log( 'tab became hidden, clearing' );
    clearInterval(alertIntervalId)
    alertIntervalId = null;
  } else {
    console.log( 'tab became visible, restarting' );
    alertIntervalId = alertIntervalId || alertInterval();
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
handleVisibilityChange();
```

Comment: i'm sorry, when copying from editor, i've forgot to paste the line  `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);` before `handleVisibilityChange()` call. So even with this line the code does not working ((((

Comment: Do you get a `alertInterval is not a function` error?

Comment: I've updated the answer after copying your code and seeing the error.

Comment: I've updated my code, please see **Edit**, but now alerts are not displaying at all (((

Comment: You forgot to call the function in the updated version: `alertIntervalId = alertIntervalId || alertInterval` should be `alertIntervalId = alertIntervalId || alertInterval();` Then I get alerts again. PS: if `randomIdx` is only used inside the timeout, better use `var randomIdx = ...`, so you don't accidentally create a global variable.

Comment: ok, thanks, fixed. Now alerts are appearing, but still not get frozen when switching to other tab ((

Comment: I can't replicate that problem. The version I'm using works for me in IE11. But since I don't have the values of `quotes`, `NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL` and `TIMEOUT_IN_SEC`, I cannot create an identical version.

Comment: thanks, i've provided values for these variables, please have a look. Are the alerts really get frozen on your system?

Comment: Yes. You will always get the last alert though. So after you tab, you will get one more alert, since you use setTimeout() inside a setInterval() but only clear the interval. So the last timeout will still run. Hence I would only use a setInterval(). You haven't explained yet why you need both, but you need to clear both.

Comment: I've updated the snippet and only changed the alerts into `console.log()`, added `var` and added some `;` Run the snippet, open a new tab, go back to the snippet tab. My results are as expected: `tab became visible, restarting
 | quote1 | quote2 | tab became hidden, clearing | quote1 | tab became visible, restarting | quote1 | quote2`.

Comment: thanks to your valuable advices, I've almost accomplished this task. I just removed setTimeout, leaving only setInterval, and now alerts are freezing as desired. But I'm still curious - is it possible to have TIMEOUT_IN_SECS delay prior to NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL countdown? Btw, initially I thought that the presence of wrapping setTimeout will provide this delay...